# Implementing swipe to refresh on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to add a `SwipeRefreshLayout` to a `RecyclerView`. How do I do that? This is the code I have but it is not working:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View consultantView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consultant, container, false);

    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) consultantView.findViewById(R.id.consultant_recyclerview);
    retrieveConsultantList();
    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            retrieveConsultantList();
            practiceSpinner.setAdapter(consultantListAdapter);
            consultantListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

And my recycler code:

```
private void setUpConsultantRecyclerView(List<Consultant>  consultantList) {
    ConsultantRecylerViewAdapter consultantRecylerViewAdapter = new ConsultantRecylerViewAdapter(getContext(), consultantList);
    consultantRecyclerView.setAdapter(consultantRecylerViewAdapter);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    consultantRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    consultantRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}
```

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: How about moving `setRefreshing(false)` until after you've updated the list?

Comment: What does `retrieveConsultantList()` do? What exactly is not working? Does it not update? Or does it not display the refreshing animation?

Comment: retrieveConsultant() loads my list from server. its not loading any data at all

Answer (score 2):

Try this changes, hopefully can help you

```
//move adapter to global variable
ConsultantRecylerViewAdapter consultantRecylerViewAdapter ;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View consultantView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consultant, container, false);
    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) consultantView.findViewById(R.id.consultant_recyclerview);

    //move to here
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    consultantRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    //declare list first
    consultantList  = new ArrayList<>();
    consultantRecylerViewAdapter  = new ConsultantRecylerViewAdapter(getContext(), consultantList);
    consultantRecyclerView.setAdapter(consultantRecylerViewAdapter);

    retrieveConsultantList();

    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            retrieveConsultantList();
            practiceSpinner.setAdapter(consultantListAdapter);
            consultantListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private void retrieveConsultantList(){
    //put this code when finish load data from server
    setUpConsultantRecyclerView(consultantListFromServer)
}

//this to refresh your RecyclerView
private void setUpConsultantRecyclerView(List<Consultant>  consultantList) {
    //clear old list
    consultantList.clear();
    //add new collection to list
    consultantList.addAll(consultantList);
    //refresh adapter
    consultantRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```